# Summary function on a subquery

Tags: sql

Can I get mean of all numbers returned in a subquery? For example, I need to attach mean of all 'y' from another table which has 'x' less than the current row's 'x'.

Something like -

```
select a.x,
mean(b.y where b.x<a.x from data2 b) as m_y
from data1 a
```

It's not working. What is the right syntax (or trick) for getting the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got it.

```
select a.x,
select(mean(b.y) where b.x<a.x from data2 b) as m_y
from data1 a
```

My sql rusted with nonuse.

Comment: I find this syntax confusing compared to a JOIN... Also, your parenthesis look in the wrong place: the whole SELECT should be inside, no?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you'd use the standard AVG aggregate.

This can be expressed as a JOIN too

```
select
   a.x,
   AVG (b.y) AS m_z
from
   data1 a
   LEFT JOIN
   data2 b ON b.x<a.x
group by
   a.x
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN`?  Doesn't the inequality make it an implicit `CROSS JOIN`?  Aren't those always left, or do they allow `RIGHT CROSS` now?

Comment: @Bacon Bits: It would be a partial cross join or what I'd call a triangular join. Either way, the result is all rows b.x<a.x will be AVG'd: I just prefer this to having sub queries usually: it matches how my brain works.